# How to make a port secure

Tags: c#, tcp, tcplistener

We are developing a server application which will listen all the connections (TCPListener) from external devices 24/7 and store these messages in our database.

For these connections, we are opening a port (let's say 13002) in our server. We would like to make this port secure which means that someone will not be able to scan ports, and connect and send thousands of requests to this specific port to make our application slow and even out of order.

Any ideas?

Comment: Configuration in router/firewall to block those request, you can't stop the request, but you can deny it. Block it from specific IP's if overuse

Comment: If you know the specific IP-Range that will be used to access the server. (Such as you would when using vpn) you could specify a bit-mask when binding the socket. That would only allow connections for a specific ip-range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If given is your definition of "secure":

> someone will not be able to scan ports, and connect and send thousands of requests to this specific port

Then a properly configured firewall will do.

That will however not prevent malicious users from doing harm to your software. If someone can figure out the protocol you use through packet inspection, they can fire arbitrary requests to your application.

This means that if your protocol is not well-designed, users can impersonate other users, send messages they're not supposed to and thus perform actions they're not allowed to.

Just putting a firewall in between will not make your protocol more secure.

Comment: It is correct, at least if these devices have fixed IPs, then we can configure the firewall in a way that it will just accept connections from these IP adresses (=devices). However, if these devices do not have fixed IP addresses, I guess it will be quite hard to filter the relevant connections (we have the chance to define the pattern of the messages sent by these devices and we can look if the pattern of the incoming message is matching with our standards. However, still we need to receive these messages and evaluate which makes our server still busy ).

Comment: And also which Port we should use? I assume the higher is better so that there will less change that other applications will use it.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)).

> In computing, a firewall is a network security system that monitors and controls the incoming and outgoing network traffic based on predetermined security rules. A firewall typically establishes a barrier between a trusted, secure internal network and another outside network, such as the Internet, that is assumed to not be secure or trusted.